# access denied when adding secrets

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I have created a key vault using a service principal. The service principal is given all the access from the policies for keys, secrets and certificates. Now when we try setting the secret using the same service principal we get access denied issue. we also see that there are no permission to list the keys and secrets though the SP has all the permissions in the access policies.

Comment: Is this related to code being written or an administration task? If there is code generating the error, please post it. If the error is appearing in the UI, you might want to try https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Could please post the script and the error message you observed? You will get a Forbidden error if the required permission is not set (e.g. Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret : Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden').

Answer (score 0):

To fix access denied you need to configure Active Directory permissions. Grant access to KeyVault.

Using **PowerShell**:

```
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName 'XXXXXXX' -ServicePrincipalName XXXXX -PermissionsToKeys decrypt,sign,get,unwrapKey
```

Using the **Azure portal**:

- Open Key Vaults
- Select **Access Policies** from the Key Vault resource blade
- Click the [+ Add new] button at the top of the blade
- Click **Select Principal** to select the application you created earlier
- From the **Key permissions** drop down, select "Decrypt", "Sign", "Get", "UnwrapKey" permissions
- Save changes

For more details, refer "[Authorize the application to use the key or secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-get-started#authorize)"

Answer (score 0):

It sounds that you have already given access to your SP with access policies and since you have a SP you probably are deploying Azure resources with that SP. Besides proper access policies you need to select “Enable access to Azure Resource Manager for template deployment” under the Advanced access policies blade. The authorization of your SP occurs after the deployment have accessed the key vault.

Answer (score 0):

I think I experienced something like this running Windows Powershell ISE.  I needed to run it under administrative privilege.